# Objective-C code coverage: ignore files

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have an test setup in Xcode to generate code coverage while running my tests. (GCOV)

My project uses a library, but my coverage is going down because i do not cover all code in that library.

Now i want to ignore those files when the coverage files are generated. Is this possible?
Or should i just delete the files after the test run with a shell script?

Comment: have you included the source code of that library in your project?

Comment: Yes, the source code is in a sub-directory in my project folder and the source files are added to my test target.

Comment: Can't you include it as a static lib or framework, thus your problem will be solved right? just a suggestion.

Comment: I wasn't able to compile the 'library' code to a static lib or framework. Yes, this would be the solution. I now prefixed all classes with the library identifier. After running my tests i use a find/rm command to remove the coverage files (*gcda and *gcno)